# Excel table in Power Query as a template to use by other excel files connected

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have strange question becuase I don't know how to create a solution to my problem.
In excel file called "Template.xlsx" I have a table (no data) with this column names:

| Date | CustomerID | OrderNo. | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

In "SalesPerson.xlsx" I have a Power Query connection to "Template.xlsx" to get information about column names to create a table with that column names.
Salesman will fill that report based on a columns from "Template.xlsx" and save it in his excel file.

I want that whenever I add a column in "Template.xlsx" the refresh of table in "SalesPerson.xlsx" won't delete data and will add a new column or change the name of existing column based on "Template.xlsx".

How to get information about new column in "SalesPerson.xlsx" without losing data?

I try to create a solution and nothing help me, because whenever I refresh "SalesPerson.xlsx" I lose all the data.

Comment: Your table gets overwritten when you refresh it. That is normal. To get around this you would need to use self-referencing table described at https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge your current data with your new data.

Let's say your query is called "XYZ" and writes to a sheet.

Take that table of data and import it back into  Power-Query. Call it "XYZ Prev".

Create a new query that starts with "XYZ Prev", selects only key columns and columns that the salesperson should be editing, removing all others. Then merge that with the data in Template.xlsx to get what you want.

Then, go into advanced editor, copy that code, and replace "XYZ"'s code with that.

Now you have a full circle! Refreshing will overwrite the existing data with *an updated version of itself!*